# Drop all tables using Slick Plain Sql queries

Tags: scala, slick

I'm using [Slick Plain Sql queries](http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/sql.html) to drop all the tables in a MariaDb database.

Here's the code I'm using:

```
import dbConfig.profile.api._
val databaseName : String

import slick.jdbc.SetParameter
implicit val SetString = SetParameter[Vector[String]](
  (s, pp) => pp.setString(s(pp.pos))
)

def dropTables = {
  val tablesToDrop : DBIO[Vector[String]] = 
    sql"SELECT concat(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '#$databaseName';".as[String]   

  val dbio : DBIO[Vector[String]] = for { 
    table <- tablesToDrop
    _ <- sqlu"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '$table';"
  } yield table

  val future = dbConfig.db.run(dbio)
  val r = Await.result(future.andThen { case _ => dbConfig.db.close },
  Duration.Inf)
}
```

It successfully gets a list of tables to delete, but then the error`Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).` I suspect this due to the `Setparameter` code.

Any ideas?

---

Here's a version using maps (i'm guessing they should be flatMaps?):

```
val tablesToDrop : DBIO[Vector[String]] = sql"SELECT concat(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '#$databaseName';".as[String]
def dropTable(tableName: String) : DBIO[Vector[String]] = sql"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS '$tableName';".as[String]
val dt = tablesToDrop.map(dbio => dbio.map(dropTable))
```

This runs without error but doesn't delete the tables. Here's the log:

```
DEBUG slick.basic.BasicBackend.action - #1: StreamingResultAction [SELECT concat(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'altairdb';]
DEBUG slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.statement - Preparing statement: SELECT concat(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = 'altairdb';
DEBUG slick.jdbc.JdbcBackend.benchmark - Execution of prepared statement took 7ms
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - /--------------------\
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | 1                  |
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | concat(table_name) |
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - |--------------------|
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | Org                |
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | OrgUser            |
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | PermissionList     |
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | PermissionType     |
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - | User               |
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - \--------------------/
DEBUG slick.jdbc.StatementInvoker.result - 1 more rows read (6 total)
DEBUG slick.basic.BasicBackend.action - #2: success Vector(slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1@3e4a6e4b, slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1@267dd7e5, slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1@6a736f6d, slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1@68834f9f, slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1@5d64cf2, slick.jdbc.SQLActionBuilder$$anon$1@4d5c7152)
```

## Update 1

Based on James's advice I wrote the following:

```
val tablesToDrop : DBIO[Vector[String]] = sql"SELECT concat(table_name) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '#$databaseName';".as[String]

def dropTable(tableNames: Vector[String]) : DBIO[Vector[String]] =
      sql"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #${tableNames.mkString(", ")};".as[String]

val dropTablesDbio : DBIO[Vector[String]] = for {
  tables <- tablesToDrop
  _  <- sqlu"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;"
  _ <- dropTable(tables)
  _ <- sqlu"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"
} yield tables
```

It works as long as the table list is non-empty. The empty list case results in a sql syntax error. Is there an elegant way to to check for an empty table?

I was thinking that if I could send

```
DBIO.seq(sqlu"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table0;",..., sqlu"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TableN;")
```

as sql then it would cover the empty table list case more elegantly.

## Update 2

This version works for no table:

```
def dropTables = {
    val tablesToDrop: DBIO[Vector[String]] = sql"SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '#$databaseName';".as[String]

    def dropTables(tableNames: Vector[String]): DBIO[Int] =
      sqlu"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #${tableNames.mkString(", ")};"

    def dropTable(name: String): DBIO[Int] = sqlu"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #$name;"

    val dropTablesDbio: DBIO[Vector[String]] = {
      tablesToDrop.flatMap(tables => {
        if (tables.isEmpty)
          DBIO.successful[Vector[String]](Vector.empty)
        else {
          for {
            _ <- sqlu"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;"
            _ <- dropTables(tables)
            _ <- sqlu"SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;"
          } yield tables
        }
      })
    }
    val future = dbConfig.db.run(dropTablesDbio.withPinnedSession)

    val r = Await.result(future, Duration.Inf)
    r.foreach(println(_))
  }
```

[Gist to this and other versions](https://gist.github.com/repositron/5d6cbd0b07db75c360e0e846b4199195)

Comment: Cool! Thanks for sharing the final version so that others also can benefit from it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS` expects a list of tables like below:

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS A, B, C`

I don't think this query accepts a bind variable(a variable to be set in a prepared statement). Instead, what you want to do is use the table names as String literals, instead of bind variables.

You don't need the `SetParameter` implicit val. Try replacing the DELETE query like below:

`DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #${table.mkString(",")};`

Ref : http://slick.lightbend.com/doc/3.2.3/sql.html#splicing-literal-values

Also worth noting that you should disable foreign key checks before you delete tables and then re-enable it after deleting them. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/4922312/2110188

Comment: Thanks for your advice James. I will try it out soon :)